# Add new records in grouped array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add new records in my grouped array. e.g

```js
var cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }];

var result = cars.reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a.make] = r[a.make] || [];
    r[a.make].push(a);
    return r;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What's the problem ? Show us what you get and what you want please.

Comment: Do you want to mutate result or do you want to create a new object?

Comment: i have seen this answer before (obviously), but what do you mean by *"add new records in my grouped array"*? You could take new data in an object with the same structure and group it later.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following will do:

```js
const result = {"audi":[{"make":"audi","model":"r8","year":"2012"},{"make":"audi","model":"rs5","year":"2013"}],"ford":[{"make":"ford","model":"mustang","year":"2012"},{"make":"ford","model":"fusion","year":"2015"}],"kia":[{"make":"kia","model":"optima","year":"2012"}]};

const addCar = (result, car) =>
    Object.keys(result).some((k) => k === car.make)//see if car exists
        ? { ...result, [car.make]: result[car.make].concat(car) }//it does
        : { ...result, [car.make]: [car] };//it does not

console.log(addCar(result, { make: 'kia', model: 'hello world' }).kia);
```